# Need suggestion on optimizing the query which calls a scalar function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, functions

--gets the configuration (team or client or default)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_config] 
(@TEAM_CONFIG BIT, @CLIENT_CONFIG BIT, @DEFAULT_CONFIG BIT)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @bit BIT = 0

    select @bit =
        CASE WHEN @TEAM_CONFIG IS NOT NULL
                THEN @TEAM_CONFIG
            WHEN @CLIENT_CONFIG IS NOT NULL 
                THEN @CLIENT_CONFIG             
            ELSE @DEFAULT_CONFIG
        END

    RETURN @bit
END
```

--add config for questions in the same order

```
    select 
  @parameterstring = CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN q.QUESTION_ID = 'question1'
                                 THEN dbo.get_config(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG) 
                                 ELSE 0
                                 END),
                            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QUESTION_ID = 'question2'
                                 THEN dbo.get_config(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG) 
                                 ELSE 0
                                 END),
                            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QUESTION_ID = 'question3'
                                 THEN dbo.get_config(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG) 
                                 ELSE 0
                                 END),
                            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QUESTION_ID = 'question4'
                                 THEN dbo.get_config(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG) 
                                 ELSE 0
                                 END),
                            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QUESTION_ID = 'question5'
                                 THEN dbo.get_config(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG) 
                                 ELSE 0
                                 END))
  from query
```

-- query itself is performing good (if there are no concatenations involved, but, there might be another way of concatenating strings with config bits in the same order...

Comment: If your version support STRING_AGG, second part of question can be simplified

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2012. Looks like STRING_AGG is not supported unfortunately.

Comment: You can mimic it with an xml function, see for example:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver&ved=2ahUKEwjdw9H-1snlAhUmwqYKHWcRCu0QjjgwAHoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3NTiH_iFDymIgHO_l03l1B

Comment: but it gets messier, so perhaps its better as is

Comment: Your function returns the same result that: `COALESCE(team.CONFIG, client.CONFIG, q.DEFAULT_CONFIG)`

Comment: Are there 5 questions only?